# Blob.decode with replacement does not seem to work

Tags: encoding, raku

This code:

```
my $þor-blob = Blob.new("þor".ords);
$þor-blob.decode( "ascii", :replacement("0"), :strict(False) ).say
```

Fails with:

```
Will not decode invalid ASCII (code point > 127 found)␤
```

And this one:

```
my $euro = Blob.new("3€".ords);
$euro.decode( "latin1", :replacement("euro") ).say
```

Simply does not seem to work, replacing € by ¬.

It's true that [those methods are not tested](https://github.com/perl6/roast/issues/524), but is the syntax right?

Comment: This question had a bounty worth `+100` reputation from me. I was looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources, hoping to get an answer from a core dev like samcv, or from someone else providing a link to core dev discussion (irc or an issue etc.) about it that either corrects or adds value to my current answer by injecting an authoritative response about what currently works and what should work in relation to `:replacement` and `:strict` for the various encodings. It looks like the original points were wasted but I'll happily redo the award if someone does as I hoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

- Only samcv or some other core dev can provide an authoritative answer. This is my understanding of the code, comments, and results I see.
- If my understanding is correct, some doc and/or code needs to be sorted out to render this SO moot.<sup>1</sup>
- Specifying the `$replacement` argument matches a different P6 core multi method than not doing so. Let's call it the "replacer" code path.
- The "replacer" code path passes the `$replacement` and `$strict` arguments onto a code path in nqp that in turn passes them onto a code path in the backend that handles replacements.
- On the MoarVM backend, the replacement and strict arguments are passed onto the decoders for the windows1252, windows1251, and shiftjis encodings *but not for other encodings*.<sup>2</sup>

## Following the relevant code path

Your code calls [this code in `Buf.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/b394b63c27c22bf6495f7bb2348fc56a47ead45d/src/core/Buf.pm6#L297):

```
multi method decode(Blob:D: $encoding,
                    Str    :$replacement!,
                    Bool:D :$strict = False) {
    nqp::p6box_s(
      nqp::decoderepconf(
        self,
        Rakudo::Internals.NORMALIZE_ENCODING($encoding),
        $replacement.defined ?? $replacement !! nqp::null_s(),
        $strict ?? 0 !! 1))
}
```

The `nqp::decoderepconf` function directly maps to a corresponding function in the backend.

On the MoarVM backend, it's [`MVM_string_decode_from_buf_config` in `ops.c`](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/6c7810ce7ca905d772ac2a3e47e73cf7c7c41ed8/src/strings/ops.c#L1781).

This in turn calls [`MVM_string_decode_config`](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/6c7810ce7ca905d772ac2a3e47e73cf7c7c41ed8/src/strings/ops.c#L1642) in the same file.

From this latter function's comments, there are a couple key sentences that presumably explain the relevance of the replacement and strictness arguments:

> Unlike `MVM_string_decode`, it will not pass through codepoints which have no official mapping.
>
> For now windows-1252 and windows-1251 are the only ones this makes a difference on.

Spelunking the code and commits in the repo suggests the latter comment is slightly out-of-date because it looks like it should make a difference on shiftjis too.

Also, to be clear, if one specifies the `$replacement` argument in P6 then the `$strict` argument is going to end up being ignored (and `$strict = True` assumed) if decoding any encoding other than the windows or shiftjis encodings.<sup>2</sup>

## What happens with ascii and latin1 in particular

The current code for `MVM_string_decode_config` does *not* pass on the replacement/strictness arguments to the `MVM_string_ascii_decode` and `MVM_string_latin1_decode` functions.

So, if you use the encoding "ascii" then the blob must only contain values between 0 and 127, and for "latin1" the values must be between 0 and 255.

```
say "þor".ords; # (254 111 114)
say "3€".ords;  # (51 8364)
```

The first string (as a `Buf`) fails to decode, and instead produces an error message, because 254 is more than 127 and [the ascii decoder code in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/strings/ascii.c) reacts to an invalid value by throwing an exception with the "invalid ASCII" message.

The second replaces `€` with `¬`. This is because by default a `Buf` is an 8 bit array, so a value above 255 gets truncated to its low byte, which for `€` is the same as `¬` (in both latin1 and Unicode).<sup>3</sup>

But it's no better if you use a `Buf` with a larger element size. The result is still a `¬`, combined with [tofu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296505/where-is-tofu-for-font-fallback-box-glyph-coming-from). I can see even if I can't C so it's clear to me that [the  `MVM_string_latin1_decode` function in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/strings/latin1.c) that decodes latin1 does not throw exceptions. So presumably when it encounters character values outside the range 0-255 it turns the higher bytes into tofu.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Of course the very thing JJ is doing that led them to post this SO in the first place is fixing the doc. I added this footnote so that other later readers would understand that context and realize that this SO is leading to changes in the doc, and may lead to changes in the code, that will presumably render this SO moot due to the work done.

<sup>2</sup> It would be nice if there were multis that rejected use of the `$replacement` argument if the decoder for the specified encoding doesn't do anything with it.

<sup>3</sup> See timotimo++'s comment below.

Comment: it's not that it does not use them. It's that I don't know how they are used, so I couldn't write the documents that explains what they do. And I know those characters are beyond the range of the representation. That's what the replacement is supposed to be for: to replace those characters (or that's what I though, and how the underlying NQP code works)

Comment: Thankis again for the answer, but that's not the code that's used. It's a Blob, which has got its own code. It's quite similar, thoough... Again, what I gather from that code is that it should replace whatever code point that can't be passed through. The tests point in that direction, also.

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Buf.pm6#L297-L309

Comment: you are right; the thing is that since you were pointing to Buf.pm6 I thought you were actually talking about Buf methods. My bad here. Thing is, it still does not answer my question. What do those methods do exactly? Looking at the NQP tests, I think they should work (substituting non-mappable characters by others)

Comment: Let me see if I got this correctly. At the end of the day, $replacement makes no difference. Or it's not needed because the codepoint passes through, or the decoding fails before getting to that. Or does that happen only for the examples that I've shown above?

Comment: the more precise answer to the latin1 part of the question is that `Blob.new` is by default `Blob[uint8].new`, which will truncate the values passed to 8 bit. That's why you get a `¬`, as that's what is encoded by `0xac`

Comment: @jjmerelo "`$replacement` makes no difference." Based on my read of the MoarVM code and comments, it works for the two windows encodings and the shiftjis encoding but does nothing for other encodings such as ascii and latin1. I've edited the question to make my answer as clear as I think I can make it.